# properly display date from database using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a creation_date displayed in my database in this format

`2014-02-03 15:59:07`

but when I'm displaying it in my page the format is

`2014-02-10T18:16:43.000Z`

What do I need to do to display it properly? I'm using JavaScript.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date = new Date("2014-02-10T18:16:43.000Z");
```

and then use some of Date methods, for example

date.toDateString() will show "Mon Feb 10 2014", or you could format by yourself by composing your own format. Like:

```
 formattedDate = date.getDate()+"."+(date.getMonth()+1)+"."+date.getFullYear();
```

and output will be `"10.2.2014"`

Comment: Forget what I said, I wasn't paying attention... +1

Comment: Thanks, I displayed it with date = new Date("2014-02-10T18:16:43.000Z"); date.toLocaleString() :)

Answer (score 0):

First select date data as unix timestamp multiplying 1000 to get miliseconds;

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_date_col) * 1000 AS ts ...
```

Then get it to Javascript (assuming that you use PHP):

```
var date2display = new Date(<?=$row['ts']?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get Date from MongoDB**

```js
InvoiceModel.find({})
    .sort({ dueDate: -1 })
    .exec((err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(data[0].dueDate);
        const dt = data[0].dueDate.toDateString();
        const date = new Date(dt);
        console.log(dt);

        console.log(date.getDate());
        console.log(date.getMonth() + 1);
        console.log(date.getFullYear());
       
        res.json({ status: 200, message: " Invoice are received", data: data });
      } else {
        res.json({ status: 401, message: err, data: {} });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please add some information/description about your answer.